# AS3 How to switch to a different scene once a set of movieclips are not visible on stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I am making an app, the app is quite simple in one part you have 4 flower petals and you pick all 4 and that takes you to a different scene that displays a logo "try again" for some reason i cant even trace the activity once these petals are picked on that stage (each petal is a movieclip). i also wrote the movieclips as variables into AS3 by linking it through classes, i dont even know if this is really necessary and i put the sentence "helloworld" to be traced when movieclip "one" is not vissible and this does not happen either. (i also tried arrays, and if("array".visible == false then gotoandplay "other scene" with the same results.) ; "the place" is the scene i want to go to once the petals are picked.

this is my current code and theres no error but it does not work as i would want it to, since it does not register that the movieclip is not visible nor does it go to the other scene.

```
var one = new sunflowerpetal10;
var two = new sunflowerpetal12;
var three = new sunflowerpetal13;
var four = new sunflowerpetal14;
var five = new sunflowerpetal15;
var six = new sunflowerpetal16;

var hello:String;
hello = "helloworld";

if(one.visible == false, two.visible == false, three.visible == false, four.visible == false, five.visible == false, six.visible == false)
{
 trace(hello); 

 gotoAndPlay(1, "theplace");
}
```

**Help please!**
are my movieclips that are already on stage not registering on AS3? or what seems to be the problem??

Comment: @ Dr.Dredel say you have 5 objects in your screen and you want to trigger them so that when all those 5 objects are invisible it will take you to a different scene. how would you do that? (object 1-5 are instances already placed on the stage, now you just want to trigger it so that once all of them are clicked you go to a different scene)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of things wrong here, and it's difficult to determine what you're actually doing. Flash is very confusing in regards to what gets referenced where and how.

For starters when you call new on something you need to give it parenthesis. so...

```
new sunflowerpetal15();
```

This assumes you have an MC called sunflowerpetal15 in your library and that this label is how's "exported to actionscript" and not just its name in the library.

Next you have to actually put this item on the stage

```
this.addChild(new sunflowerpetal15());
```

next in your if statement you have ,s which are illegal. I think you mean && (logical and) between your items, but again, not sure what you're doing).

When all of that is fixed, you *should have it go and play frame 1 but I suspect you've never left frame 1 to begin with! so... again, I suspect you're not clear on what you're doing here.

What you *really need is a good step by step tutorial on getting started in Flash and AS3. You're all over the map and Flash is the ABSOLUTELY wrong environment to go it alone without a good guide because it's profoundly un-intuitive.

Comment: thank you very much! and yeah, i learnt about flash however i had the lessons that didnt involve any actionscript from my ipod, then after realized how crippled that left me so im trying to learn, thank you so much for the info though!

Comment: I found a solution, here is my code, Each petal has this code on attached to them

Answer (score 0):

The ANSWER!:

Each one of the petals has this code ( which is the code to make the object invisible once you click on it) :

```
sunflowerpetal1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToHide);

function fl_ClickToHide(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    sunflowerpetal1.visible = false;
}
```

- now everytime i tried to do an `if` statement so that once all of the petals were gone it would pass to another screen it wouldn't work!

Ex:

```
if(sunflowerpetal1.visible == false && sunflowerpetal2.visible == false && sunflowerpetal3.visible == false && sunflowerpetal4.visible == false && sunflowerpetal5.visible == false && sunflowerpetal6.visible == false)
{
    gotoAndPlay(1, "theplace");
}
```

- the trick was to put this "if" statement inside the brackets of each one of the petals current code like so:

  sunflowerpetal1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToHide);

  function fl_ClickToHide(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
      sunflowerpetal1.visible = false;

  ```
  if(sunflowerpetal1.visible == false && sunflowerpetal2.visible == false && sunflowerpetal3.visible == false && sunflowerpetal4.visible == false && sunflowerpetal5.visible == false && sunflowerpetal6.visible == false)
  ```

  {
      gotoAndPlay(1, "theplace");
  }

  }

*put that "if" statement inside everyone of the petals(or disappearing objects) codes and you will be all set, once you click all of the petals ( or movie clips) you will be sent to the scene you command it to. (i had 6 petals to be clicked before bringing you to a different screen called `"theplace"` that says "try again")

**Problem solved =)**